# Wicket: only change single component (label) in ListView

Tags: java, ajax, listview, listviewitem, wicket-6

I'm trying to modify a Label for only **one out of four** items in my ListView.
The idea is to display a extend / collapse option.

Right now I have following code (shortend):

```
public class EditZustaendigkeit extends WebPage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Form<Void> mainForm = new Form<Void>("mainForm");
@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "rawtypes" })
private ListView listView;
private ListItemZustaendigkeit lstItZust;

public EditZustaendigkeit() {
    Application.get().getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(true); 
    this.add(mainForm);

    mainForm.add(listView = new ListView<Institut>("listView", getInstitute()) {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
        private AjaxLink extenderInstitut;
        private Label institutStateLabel;
        Model<String> modelForInstitute = Model.of("+");
        private boolean isCollapsed = true;

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Institut> item) {
            item.add(extenderInstitut = new AjaxLink<String>("extenderInstitut") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                    if(isCollapsed){
                        modelForInstitute.setObject("-");
                        isCollapsed = false;
                    } else if(!isCollapsed){
                        modelForInstitute.setObject("+");
                        isCollapsed = true;
                    }
                    setResponsePage(getPage());
                }
            });
            extenderInstitut.add(institutStateLabel = new Label("stateLabel", modelForInstitute));
            institutStateLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);         
        }
    });
}
```

So now when I run the Application I get 4 ListView items like planed, but when I press one of the links, all 4 links change.
This is of course because in the ListView they all share the same markup.
I just don't know how to solve it **without JavaScript**, is it even to do so? If yes, how?

Please remember: This is not the full code, just the snippet where the bug has to be.

And as bonus: Is the whole thing possible without a page refresh or isn't it possible for the markup to change without it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `modelForInstitute` and `isCollapsed` are shared between all `ListItem`s because they are members of the ListView.
Make them local variables instead:

```
final IModel<String> labelModel = Model.of("+");
item.add(extenderInstitut = new AjaxLink<String>("extenderInstitut") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                String label = labelModel.getObject();
                if("+".equals(label)){
                    labelModel.setObject("-");
                } else if(!isCollapsed){
                    labelModel.setObject("+");
                }
                target.add(mainForm);
            }
        });
        extenderInstitut.add(institutStateLabel = new Label("stateLabel", labelModel));
```

Some extra notes:

- move `Application.get().getMarkupSettings().setStripWicketTags(true);` to `YourApplication#init()` method
- you can use `AjaxLink#setBody(IModel label)` instead of adding a Label component. This way your component tree will be smaller

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
link.add(new Label("Id", new LoadableDetachableModel (){public String load(){return isClicked?"-":"+"}})
```

I do not know if API is OK because I send it from mobile but you can look for examples on internet on LoadableDetachableModel.

Comment: Inside populateItem I have to set the variable final, so I'm not able to change it anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul wicket:id="listContainer">
    <li wicket:id="list">
        <span wicket:id="item"></span>
        <a href="#" wicket:id="link">expand</a>
        <span wicket:id="expandable">now you see me</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Java:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3");
List<String> expanded = new ArrayList<>();

public TestPage() {

    WebMarkupContainer listContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("listContainer");
    listContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    listContainer.add(new ListView<String>("list", new PropertyModel<>(this, "items")) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> listItem) {
            final String item = listItem.getModelObject();

            listItem.add(new Label("item", item));

            listItem.add(new AjaxLink<String>("link") {

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                    if (expanded.contains(item)) {
                        expanded.remove(item);
                    } else {
                        expanded.add(item);
                    }
                    ajaxRequestTarget.add(listContainer);
                }
            });

            listItem.add(new WebMarkupContainer("expandable") {

                @Override
                public boolean isVisible() {
                    return expanded.contains(item);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    add(listContainer);
}
```

To refresh only part of the page after ajax action you need to add component you want to refresh to AjaxRequestTarget, and this component must have outputMarkupId set to true.